# What is the image of the Ramanujan Delta function?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, modular-forms

Consider the Ramanujan $\Delta$ function as a map from the upper half plane to the complex plane. We know that the image of $\Delta$ is unbounded and that it does not contain the point $0$. What else do we know about the image?

Answer (score 5):

For every nonzero complex number $w$, there is some $z \in \mathbb{H}$ so that $\Delta(z) = w$. This follows from the fact that for any elliptic curve $E : y^{2} = 4x^{3} - A x - B$ (that is, $A^{3} - 27B^{2} \ne 0$), there is a unique lattice $\Lambda$ for which $g_{2}(\Lambda) = A$ and $g_{3}(\Lambda) = B$. A proof is given in Theorem 2.9 of Apostol's "Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory."